# removeExtra(key) in activity intent will cause cannot add it back again

Tags: android

I have 3 activites, they're: **A**, **Main** and **B**.

A and B both can start and switch to **Main** and vice versa, but I just want when **Main** knows it was started by **A**, then doing sth, so I put an intent extra ONLY in **A** when it starts **Main**:

```
/*In Activity A*/
Intent intent = new Intent(A_Activity.this, Main_Activity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);                                    
intent.putExtra("myKey", true);
startActivity(intent);
```

once **Main** gets the value, starts doing sth, everything is good:

```
    /*in MainActivity*/
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        boolean shouldDo = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("myKey", false);
        if (shouldDo) {
          // do sth
        }
    }
```

the problem is the `myKey` seems persisted in `intent`, so from now on, even the route is from **B** to **Main**, the above code will also be executed by **Main**, so I put a `remove extra` in Main, likes swallow `myKey`:

```
    /*in Main_Activity*/
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        boolean shouldDo = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("myKey", false);
        if (shouldDo) {
          getIntent().removeExtra("myKey");
          // do sth
        }
    }
```

then, here comes the issue when I doing this case: switched **from Main to A**, and then come back again.    Then the **Main** would never detect that `myKey` anymore, what's the problem here?

Comment: Can you check to see if `MainActivity.onNewIntent()` is being called? I think it could be the case that every time `MainActivity` starts (after the first one) the `Intent`s from `A` or `B` are being delivered here. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent(android.content.Intent)

Comment: Yes, I can see my EMPTY `onNewIntent(Intent intent)` is called right before the `onResume(...)`, not quite understand the officical doc said, does it explained my case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `MainActivity` is launched for a second (or third, etc) time using `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP`, the process by which the activity is shown is a little different from normal. Rather than a new activity being created, the system is re-using your existing activity.

The `Intent` object that you get when you call `getIntent()` is the one passed to the activity the very first time you open it. Every time after, the `Intent` you use to re-launch `MainActivity` will be passed to `onNewIntent()` instead.

The solution is to re-think how you access the `Intent` extra you're using in `onResume()`. Do something like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private boolean shouldDo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        shouldDo = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("myKey", false);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        shouldDo = intent.getBooleanExtra("myKey", false);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (shouldDo) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

In other words, set the value of `shouldDo` using `getIntent()` the first time, and using the `Intent` passed to `onNewIntent()` every time thereafter.

Comment: This is a little confuse that my logical has to depends on how current Activity created, so someday I create `MainActivity` without `SINGLE_TOP`, the `onNewIntent()` will not be called anymore, correct?

Comment: Yes, `onNewIntent()` is only called when an activity is re-launched. You can read more here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent(android.content.Intent)